# Java Swing dispose() vs. setVisible(false)

Tags: java, swing, visibility, dispose

I have a standalone Java application that gets data from a database and displays it in a `JTable`.  When the application starts, the user is prompted for a username/password in a `JDialog`.  Once the correct credentials are entered, the main `JFrame` containing the data is displayed.  On the main `JFrame` I have a logout button that, when clicked, should close the main `JFrame` and redisplay the login `JDialog`.  Everything is mostly working except I have found that the main `JFrame` does not go away when the logout button is clicked.  Below is a small working example of my code:

**Main.java:**

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainFrame.java:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button;
    private MyDialog dialog;
    
    public MainFrame() {
        super("this is the JFrame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog = new MyDialog(this);
        button = new JButton("click me to hide this JFrame and display JDialog");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(false); // works when changed to dispose();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**MyDialog.java:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MyDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame parentFrame;
    private JButton button;
    
    public MyDialog(JFrame parentFrame) {
        super(parentFrame, "this is the JDialog", true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.parentFrame = parentFrame;
        button = new JButton("click me to hide JDialog and show JFrame");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(false);
        parentFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In **MainFrame.java** if I change the line that says `setVisible(false)` to `dispose()` then the JFrame goes away when I click the button.  My question is, why does this work with `dispose()` and not with `setVisible(false)`?  Is there a better way for me to organize my code?  I am new to Swing so I apologize if this is a basic question.  Thank you.

---

**EDITED 2011-10-19 10:26 PDT**

Thank you everyone for your help.  I changed the `JDialog` to have a null parent and now everything works as I wanted.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the line where you initiate the JDialog:

```
dialog = new MyDialog(this);
```

You're setting the same frame as the parent frame that the dialog sits on.  You see, a dialog can't appear on its own, it must sit on top of a parent frame.

So in your code, when you write:

```
setVisible(false); // works when changed to dispose();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

In the first line you tell the frame to disappear, then you tell the dialog to appear, which really tells the dialog to appear on its parent frame.  Since the parent frame is the same it looks like it stays visible to you.  If you remove the second line, I'm sure the frame would disappear.  But when you tell the frame to dispose, it disappears entirely because you told it not just to lose visibility, but also remove itself from memory.

Then when you tell the dialog to appear it looks for its JFrame (which has been disposed), re-initializes it and opens up.

The way to solve your problem is to make a separate new JFrame for the JDialog.  Then don't use dispose and just use the setVisible command.

-Asaf

Comment: It could just be sufficient to not make the frame it reopens its parent frame. So, make the super call in `MyDialog()` go: `super(null, "this is the JDialog", false);`. If the main frame is hidden it won't receive meaningful input anyway, so there's no reason to make the dialog modal.

Comment: @Inerdia You are correct, that is also an option.  I forgot that the boolean there is for modality.  Also, I'm fairly certain the boolean modality has been deprecated and the ModalityType method is now preferred.

Comment: Not really deprecated, at least not officially. It's specified which boolean value corresponds to which modality type, so it's probably just a question of style which one you prefer.

Comment: @Inerdia Interesting, because if you try to use setModal(boolean modal) in eclipse it is marked as deprecated.

Comment: In the version of Java that ships with OS X, it's not marked that way in the docs (neither with `@Deprecated`, or the corresponding javadoc tag), and I don't get the compiler warning when building with javac from IntelliJ, so I'd chalk that up to Eclipse having its own opinion of this. The docs mention `setModal()` is "obsolete", so that might be the motivation. (They don't say that about the constructors though.)

Comment: @Inerdia yeah it's my fault for mixing up "obsolete" and "deprecated".  And you're right, the docs say nothing about the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I will simply give correct code, in my own style. It certainly is not the single or even proven best solution.

setVisible(false) on the main frame should invoke the close operation, logically for a main frame EXIT_ON_CLOSE. If the dialog is a child of the main frame, then the application exits.

So I made the modal dialog a second top window, which has a (JFrame)null as parent. Hence you have an application with two top windows. And the modal dialogs are every time disposed.
I made the modal dialog DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, as you do not want the Close icon to function.
Hence the dispose() in the actionPerformed.
(If you at any time have a parent, you may use getOwner() instead of copying the parent to a field.)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
                mainFrame.actionPerformed(null);
            }
        });
    }
}


public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button;

    public MainFrame() {
        super("this is the JFrame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button = new JButton("click me to hide this JFrame and display JDialog");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);
        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(MainFrame.this);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);
    }
}


public class MyDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button;
    private JFrame parentFrame;

    public MyDialog(JFrame parentFrame) {
        super((JFrame)null, "this is the JDialog", false);
        this.parentFrame = parentFrame;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        button = new JButton("click me to hide JDialog and show JFrame");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        parentFrame.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think setVisible invokes the close operation. It just hides the frame/dialog...